# File execution leads to 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 4707: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cqlsh

I would like to execute many files containing commands for an application. These commands may contains variables with many German characters such as ä,ü,ö,ß etc. Therefore, I used `os.system` to execute the file:

```
os.system("cqlsh -f test.cql")
```

But upon execution for that application, I am getting this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 4707: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

The sample `test.cql` file is as follows:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS xyz.table_metadata( 
id UUID primary key, 
"0325799.GET.PT.T_6_GNR_62_T256_AR_Gehäuse_Ohm" frozen <signal_0325799GETPTT_6_GNR_62_T256_AR_Gehuse_Ohm>, 
"0325799.UMR.KS.T_rü_1" frozen <signal_0325799UMRKST_r_1>);
```

How may I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to set the utf-8 encoding environment which that particular application supports, as:

```
os.system("cqlsh -f test.cql --encoding utf-8")
```

But the error remains the same.

Comment: What happens if you run `cqlsh -f test.cql` directly from the command prompt?

Comment: Is it an option to use python 3 instead? The problems may be gone there, because it has more accomodating defaults.

Comment: @Robᵩ I tested that in the command prompt and also within `cqlsh` environment with `source` command. Both led me to the same error, it is because, what I observe is due to the umlauts and non-ascii characters. But I am quite puzzled as why it is not working even when I force it into UTF8 environment

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Unfortunately, no. :(

Comment: If it fails from the command line, then this has nothing to do with `os.system()`. Rephrase your question, focus the cqlsh command, remove the [tag:python] tags and add a [tag:cqlsh] tag so that the cqlsh experts can help you .

Comment: Which version of CQLSH are you using?

Comment: @ands It is 5.0.1